# Proof of equation for inverse of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, inverse

Well, I'm curently learning Linear Algebra from MIT OpenCourse 18.06 with Profesor Strang.

I'm currently at [video 20](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QNpj-gOXW9M) about Cramer's rule, about the equation for inverse of a matrix and I quite don't understand the 'proof'.

the proof starts about 3:30

Well, I quite don't get one thing:

We start from formula $A^{-1} = \frac{1}{detA} C^{T}$   where $C$ is matrix of cofactors of matrix A.

We change it to : $A C^T = (detA)I$

$$
\pmatrix{
a_{11}  & \dots & a_{1n} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{n1} & \dots  & a_{nn} }
\pmatrix{
C_{11}  & \dots & C_{n1} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
C_{1n} & \dots  & C_{nn} }
=
\pmatrix{
detA  & \dots & 0  \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & \dots  & detA }
$$

I really just can't understand how the last matrix should be the same as $ (detA) I$

shouldnt it be  $ (detA)^ {n} I$  because we have $detA$ on every line of identity matrix?

Also can't understand why there are zeros on non diagonal ...

Is there something I missed??

EDIT: I already understood that about getting detA before matrix.. Such a basic thing.. But still i'm not able to understand the second part...

So my question now is:

Why when we multiply row a from A and row b from C when $ a \neq b$ why it is 0 ??

Comment: A constant multiplying the identity matrix results in that constant being every element on the diagonal.  You don't need a power of the constant for every row; scalar multiplication multiplies the entire matrix at once.

Comment: @Paul  Yeah i know I was thinking about it very weirdly after day of learning about determinants.. I realized my mistake there...